# I have some issues while providing data path in jupyter note

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I am facing issues in data path using Jupyter Notebook:

[data_path='E:\7th Semester\FYP\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Ysg.png)

I am experiencing the following error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-22eb7ee6dcc7> in <module>
      1 for pt in pts:
      2     file = data_path + pt
----> 3     annotation = wfdb.rdann(file, 'atr')
      4     sym = annotation.symbol
      5 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfdb\io\annotation.py in rdann(record_name, extension, sampfrom, sampto, shift_samps, pn_dir, return_label_elements, summarize_labels)
   1625 
   1626     # Read the file in byte pairs
-> 1627     filebytes = load_byte_pairs(record_name, extension, pn_dir)
   1628 
   1629     # Get WFDB annotation fields from the file bytes

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfdb\io\annotation.py in load_byte_pairs(record_name, extension, pn_dir)
   1748     # local file
   1749     if pn_dir is None:
-> 1750         with open(record_name + '.' + extension, 'rb') as f:
   1751             filebytes = np.fromfile(f, '<u1').reshape([-1, 2])
   1752     # PhysioNet file

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\x07th Semester\\FYP\\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0100.atr'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with double backslashes (or raw strings):

```
data_path='E:\\7th Semester\\FYP\\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0'


data_path=r'E:\7th Semester\FYP\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to your path -

You can use [r-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals) available in python

```
#### set data_path as below - 

data_path=r'E:\7th Semester\FYP\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0\mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0'
```

**Note - Do not add the closing forward slash at the end , when using r**

Comment: it works but it doesn't show me any output

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot a slash between "mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0" and "100" in your variable "file".

[Your path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzfOb.png)